# could not find driver in laravel

Tags: php, pdo, laravel-5.5

As I run `php artisan migrate` command it output

> In Connection.php line 664:
>   could not find driver (SQL: select * from information_schema.tables
>   where t     able_schema = employee and table_name = migrations)
>   In PDOConnection.php line 47: 
>                               could not find driver                              In PDOConnection.php line 43:
>                                could not find driver

and also i have pdo enabled for mysql, pgsql, sqlite 
im using ubuntu 16 and PHP Version 7.2.8 and laravel 5.5

Comment: Use `php -m` command to check whether `mysql, pgsql, sqlite` modules are installed.

Comment: Try unninstalling the PDO and installing it again using: `apt-get install php-mysql`, when you install it, it should already register and enable it's own dependencies. You can test if it's enabled creating a file with this content: `<?php phpinfo(); ?>` in the indexed/public folder of your server.

Comment: @Rafael i created it and it shows pdo enabled for mysql, pgsql, sqlite

Comment: @LovepreetSingh i use your command it output a list and list does not have mysql, pgsql, sqlite

Comment: You could also try installing the driver specifically for the php version you have, though I don't see how that could be any different than the previous command: `$ apt-get install php7.2-mysql`

Comment: thanx @Rafael i run first command and it works for me thnx

Comment: migration works but when i try to register on browser  it shows  Illuminate \ Database \ QueryException
could not find driver (SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from `users` where `email` = ankit@gmail.com)

Comment: I'm gonna add an answer with that line then.

Answer (score 13):

Use `php -m` command to check whether `mysql, pgsql, sqlite` modules are installed.

If not listed then use following command to install.

```
apt-get install php7.2-mysql php7.2-pgsql php7.2-sqlite
```

Answer (score 11):

You need to install `php-mysql` package. `sudo apt install php-mysql` will work but it will download the plugin for the latest PHP version.

If your PHP version is not the latest, then you can add version in it:

```
# PHP 7.1
sudo apt install php7.1-mysql

# PHP 7.2:
sudo apt install php7.2-mysql

# PHP 7.3
sudo apt install php7.3-mysql

# PHP 7.4
sudo apt install php7.4-mysql

# PHP 8
sudo apt install php-mysql
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked if the table migrations exist on the database?

You could try to run:

`php artisan migrate:install`

and after that you can try your (what I think you were doing to get the error):

`php artisan migrate --seed`

Answer (score 0):

Try unninstalling the PDO and installing it again using:

```
$ apt-get install php-mysql
```

When you install it, it should already register and enable it's own dependencies.

You can test if it's enabled creating a file with this content:

```
<?php phpinfo(); ?>
```

In the indexed/public folder of your server.

Answer (score 0):

try to install php-mysql with following command sudo apt-get install php-mysql and restart your server