# How to solve "could not find driver" in laravel?

Tags: mysql, laravel, mariadb

I'm working with laravel on Manjaro and I installed php and Mariadb.
in my laravel project when it wants to connect to database it show me "Illuminate\Database\QueryException
could not find driver (SQL: select * from `users` where `email` = sample.co@example.com limit 1) ";
database config:

```
      'mysql' => [
          'driver' => 'mysql',
          'url' => env('DATABASE_URL'),
          'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
        'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
        'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
        'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
        'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
        'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),
        'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
        'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
        'prefix' => '',
        'prefix_indexes' => true,
        'strict' => true,
        'engine' => null,
        'options' => extension_loaded('pdo_mysql') ? array_filter([
            PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA => env('MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA'),
        ]) : [],
    ],
My env file:
 DB_CONNECTION=mysql
 DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
 DB_PORT=3306
 DB_DATABASE=farsifor_m
 DB_USERNAME=root
 DB_PASSWORD=mypassword
```

Comment: hey you should check your installation. If you are using wamp or xampp, please reinstall and let me know.
 sudo apt-get install php7.1-sqlite3

Comment: Does this answer your question? [could not find driver in laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51982770/could-not-find-driver-in-laravel)

Comment: I installed php and mariadb by pacman @Ali Fidanli

Answer (score 0):

I replaced php8 by php 7.4 . It solved the issue.